# Customizing Flex Slider plugin

Tags: wordpress

I've looked a looked and looked for the perfect rotating banner for my website I am creating and I found flex slider, of which I love as it gives you the circled just underneath and the left and right arrows as well. The option for face or slide is what I was looking for too, however I need a plugin that allows the user to upload an image to the banner like Useful banner Manager. (I'm not using UBM as I don't what each banner image to fade to white and then to the next image, but that's how it acts).

Does anyone know a great rotating banner plugin that is easy to follow for wordpress newbies (as this will be integrated into the websites I create for clients) either free or premium?

OR do you know how I might just add the upload option to the flex slider plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you know the data format that the Flex Slider uses you can simply create a custom post type called 'Banner', restrict the various stock metaboxes, leaving say, only the editor and media upload. Then your clients can simply create new 'banners' by creating a new banner post, and uploading its associated image. This is a nice, simple and easy to understand interface for clients, making it easy for them to add, remove, edit banners.

Then simply do a get_posts on your banners and provide the Flex slider with data in a format it expects.

This has the advantage of not requiring a plugin to create, which is useful if you are distributing themes.

http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Types

Comment: That sounds great. I've just started working with post types so I'll have to read up more on them and look through it all but thanks!

Comment: Cool. I think its a more elegant solution than requiring a plugin for a theme, as this requires the user install the plugin etc, whereas a solution like the above, works out of the box.